# Flipping an image vertically in Python without using flip() method

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to flip an image vertically without using any default flip() or similar functions.I tried to iterate along the pixels and by using loops tried to reverse it so i can flip the image vertically.

```
image=cv2.imread('boat.jpg',1)
height,width,channel=image.shape
list1=[]
list2=[]
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        list1.append(image[i,j])
for a in range(len(list1)-1,-1,-1):
     list2.append(list1[a])
b=0
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        image[i,j]=list2[b]
        b+=1
```

But the flipped image is looking like this: https://ibb.co/KKVkd2d
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Since you're already using OpenCV, why not just use [`flip`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaca7be533e3dac7feb70fc60635adf441) for this? I'd be something like `flipped_image = cv2.flip(image, 0)`. Do you explicitly want to use a loop to do the flipping manually?

Comment: @martineau Please don't further use the `cv2` tag, since it's pending removal (see tag wiki excerpt). `python` and `opencv` tags are preferred here.

Comment: Yeah i want to create my own flip function without using cv2.flip() method or any other methods which is similar.

Comment: Beside the typo in `len(list)` works fine here

Comment: I corrected it but the output image is still wrong.

Comment: you have to move rows, not pixels - reverse rows in array.

Comment: I would suggest you try Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick. They have all sorts of methods to do things like that in one simple command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flip vertically you have to reverse rows in array - first row has to be last, last row has to be first. You don't have to move pixels in rows.

```
import cv2
import numpy 

image = cv2.imread('boat.jpg', 1)

image = numpy.array(list(reversed(image)))

cv2.imshow('window', image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

---

**BTW:** if you want to flip horizontally then you have to reverse pixels in rows.

```
import cv2
import numpy 

image = cv2.imread('boat.jpg', 1)

image = numpy.array([list(reversed(row)) for row in image])

cv2.imshow('window', image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I would use `cv2.flip`. Decomposing the image into lists of rows of pixels and reversing the list is more computationally intrusive. https://techtutorialsx.com/2019/04/21/python-opencv-flipping-an-image/

Comment: OP in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814369/flipping-an-image-vertically-in-python/58815224?noredirect=1#comment103907115_58814369) said that he want to do it without `cv2.flip` :)

Comment: Oh I missed the comments. I just looked at the question. Thanks!